# AWS EMR v5.32.0 Bootstrap Numpy Issue

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-emr

I am launching a EMR cluster from EC2 machine using custom script. In bootstrap script I have mentioned to upgrade numpy so that it can be compatible with pandas. But when I try to import pandas it says it require numpy version greater than 1.16. On checking I found that there are two version of numpy available 1.16 and 1.21. I have given uninstall command in bootstrap but it is not removing the previous version. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on this - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=989210&tstart=0 - I think you can try to downgrade your pandas in bootstrap script instead of upgrading numpy.